# What is the space complexity of a function that creates a variable of value `N!` (N factorial)?

Tags: python, factorial, space-complexity

The bit-length an integer of value `N` is `O(lgN)`.

What is the bit-length of an integer of value `N!` (i.e. `N` factorial)? If a function gets passed in a list of length `N` and it creates a variable of value `N!`, what is the space complexity of the function?

Example function:

```
def numPermutations(nums):
    '''Precondition: `nums` is a list of distinct numbers'''
    N = len(nums)
    return math.factorial(N)
```

Would the function have `O(1)` space complexity since it creates only one integer variable (i.e. `N`) and it's conceivable that the a sensible implementation of `math.factorial` would also only create at most a couple integer variables? Or would it be `O(lgN!)` since the bit-length of `N!` is on the order of `lg2(N!)`?

(Side note: `lg2(N!) ==`  sum from `i = 1` to `N` of `lg2(i)`.)

---

I coded the following to create some data:

```
from math import factorial

for N in range(100):
    print(f'{N}, {factorial(N).bit_length()}')
```

The data is visualized in this Desmos: [Bit-length of N!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/izgebpjbto). The Desmos also includes a few functions/regressions that match the data.

Comment: The function has a different space complexity when viewed in different ways. It has O(1) in terms of the number of integers of unlimited size (only a theoretical construct) but O(log(N!)) in terms of bits (or some other finite-sized unit). 

Also, O(lg(N!)) is the same as O(log(N!)), we can neglect the constant log base because of how big O notation is defined.

Comment: @skywalker thanks! Do you distinguish between `lg` and `log`? If so what bases do you assign to each? `e` and `10` respectively? Or `2` and `10`?

Also, suppose we have a function like `def foo(nums): N = len(nums); return N//2`.  It'd have an `O(1)` space complexity in terms of the number of integers of unlimited size, right? But it'd have an `O(log(N))` space complexity in terms of bits, right?

Comment: I think lg sometimes means base 2 and sometimes base 10. People use log in big O notation because the base is unimportant (meaning ANY logarithm). Your function has O(N) space complexity because `nums` is an array that you need to keep in memory where N is the length of the `nums` array.

Comment: The big O notation is universal and can be used for almost anything (for example bits, time, space etc.) But keep in mind that it removes all constants, so it does not matter if the units are seconds or years.

Comment: I think your `foo` function would have O(Nlog N) space complexity in terms of bits because you have to store every number in the array and every number takes up O(log N) bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), you can assume `n! ~ c*sqrt(n)*n^n`. Therefore, `log(n!) ~ n*log(n)`, which is the space complexity of `n!`.